# Mongo Remove records in a huge collection

Tags: mongodb, limit

I have a huge collection (1000 Million) and I would like to search and remove the records older than a timestamp.

I have an index created on the field *lastUpdatedTime*

```
   db.MyCol.remove({"lastUpdatedTime" : {$lt: ISODate("2016-10-06 00:00:00 AM") }})
```

The above remove query timeouts and I modified to use BulkOperation as well.

> Failed execution of command 'delete' with id 4334 on connection
>   'connectionId{localValue:13, serverValue:22}' to server 'XXXXX:27017'
>   with exception 'com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout
>   while receiving message'

I understand mongo doesn't support limit in remove yet. So, I am implementing something like below

```
//Read 10K records            
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("lastUpdatedTime", 
               new BasicDBObject("$lte", new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis())));
DBCursor cursorDocBuilder = myCol.find(query).limit(10000);
// Get Ids
BasicDBList inList = new BasicDBList();
 while (cursorDocBuilder.hasNext())
  {
     inList.add(cursorDocBuilder.next().get("_id"));
   }
//construct In clause
 BasicDBObject deleteQuery = new BasicDBObject();
 deleteQuery.put("_id", new BasicDBObject(MongoOps.$IN, inList));
 WriteResult result =myCol.remove(deleteQuery);
```

1. What would be a good number to remove using $IN clause?
2. Will it better to fire multiple remove statements instead a big one with many IN clause?
3. I think this is a everyday situation to delete the top N records in a database. Is there a better way of achieving this?

P.S : I can do multiple threads to clean up. I don't want to throttle the database as I anticipate high read /write operations to the same collection.

Adding the explain() for fetching 1000 records

```js
{
 "queryPlanner" : {
  "plannerVersion" : 1,
  "namespace" : "XXX",
  "indexFilterSet" : false,
  "parsedQuery" : {
   "lastUpdatedTime" : {
    "$lt" : ISODate("2016-10-06T00:00:00Z")
   }
  },
  "winningPlan" : {
   "stage" : "LIMIT",
   "limitAmount" : 1000,
   "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "inputStage" : {
     "stage" : "IXSCAN",
     "keyPattern" : {
      "lastUpdatedTime" : 1
     },
     "indexName" : "lastUpdatedTime_1",
     "isMultiKey" : false,
     "multiKeyPaths" : {
      "lastUpdatedTime" : [ ]
     },
     "isUnique" : false,
     "isSparse" : false,
     "isPartial" : false,
     "indexVersion" : 2,
     "direction" : "forward",
     "indexBounds" : {
      "lastUpdatedTime" : [
       "(true, new Date(1475712000000))"
      ]
     }
    }
   }
  },
  "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
 },
 "executionStats" : {
  "executionSuccess" : true,
  "nReturned" : 1000,
  "executionTimeMillis" : 200,
  "totalKeysExamined" : 1000,
  "totalDocsExamined" : 1000,
  "executionStages" : {
   "stage" : "LIMIT",
   "nReturned" : 1000,
   "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 201,
   "works" : 1001,
   "advanced" : 1000,
   "needTime" : 0,
   "needYield" : 0,
   "saveState" : 10,
   "restoreState" : 10,
   "isEOF" : 1,
   "invalidates" : 0,
   "limitAmount" : 1000,
   "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "nReturned" : 1000,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 201,
    "works" : 1000,
    "advanced" : 1000,
    "needTime" : 0,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 10,
    "restoreState" : 10,
    "isEOF" : 0,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 1000,
    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
    "inputStage" : {
     "stage" : "IXSCAN",
     "nReturned" : 1000,
     "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
     "works" : 1000,
     "advanced" : 1000,
     "needTime" : 0,
     "needYield" : 0,
     "saveState" : 10,
     "restoreState" : 10,
     "isEOF" : 0,
     "invalidates" : 0,
     "keyPattern" : {
      "lastUpdatedTime" : 1
     },
     "indexName" : "lastUpdatedTime_1",
     "isMultiKey" : false,
     "multiKeyPaths" : {
      "lastUpdatedTime" : [ ]
     },
     "isUnique" : false,
     "isSparse" : false,
     "isPartial" : false,
     "indexVersion" : 2,
     "direction" : "forward",
     "indexBounds" : {
      "lastUpdatedTime" : [
       "(true, new Date(1475712000000))"
      ]
     },
     "keysExamined" : 1000,
     "seeks" : 1,
     "dupsTested" : 0,
     "dupsDropped" : 0,
     "seenInvalidated" : 0
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "timeout"? Are you using RoboMongo when this timeout occurs? It's notorious for this. If it's a long running query then the issue will be a lack of an index on the field in the query. Adding an index though is of course going to take time as well. So it's really just a question of A. Just let the slow remove run and create a fresh index afterwards B. Create an index and wait for that to complete, then have a faster delete remove both the data and index entries. There is no really any other way around that. Use the `mongo` shell instead, which does not timeout.

Comment: There's no need for your approach here as 10000 or 1000000 is not something MongoDB should sweat over, and won't. The content in the comment is more relevant than writing something convulted to work around what should be a simple issue as long as you consider how queries actually work.

Comment: Thanks! My code timeouts with Failed execution of command 'delete' with id 4334 on connection 'connectionId{localValue:13, serverValue:22}' to server 'XXXXX:27017' with exception 'com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message'

Comment: And yes, I do have an index in the lastUpdatedTimestamp.

Comment: Can you edit your post showing the defined index with output from the `mongo` shell please? Can you also do an `db.MyCol.explain("executionStats").find({"lastUpdatedTime" : {$lt: new Date("2016-10-06") } }).limit(1000)` in the shell and include that "explain" output as well. This should tell us something about what is happening in the query execution.

Comment: Timeout occurs when I try to remove and not find with limit . I have modified my original post to reflect the same.

Comment: I know that. I want the "query" with the "explain output" so we can see what is happening in the execution. The only reason the `limit()` is there is so that that "sample query output" does not run forever and timeout as well. Understand why I am asking for that now? Please run that in the `mongo` shell and include the output in your question. Ir will help.